# using strings in NOT IN mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT EMAIL FROM USERNAME WHERE EMAIL <> '".$_REQUEST['EMAIL']."' AND EMAIL NOT IN (".$str.")") or die("Error: ". mysql_error(). " with query ". $sql);
```

for example $str holds the value 'd','f' and there is a d and f in the EMAIL column in my table.

When I run the query I get this error "Error: Unknown column 'd' in 'where clause' with query"

I am a complete noob to mysql so I hope I'm just missing something very basic here.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com) hole there. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

The `IN` syntax works either as

```
WHERE field IN (value1, value2, value3, ...)
```

or

```
WHERE value IN (field1, field2, field3, ...)
```

Given you're getting the 'no such `d`, you're probably forgetting to quote those values, producing

```
WHERE field IN (d, f)
```

which is interpeted as "field d" and "field f", where it shoul be:

```
WHERE field IN ('d', 'f')
```

Note the quotes - they turn those d and f's into strings, not field names.

Comment: thats what I'm not understanding, I'm sure the variable in between the () is set to 'd','f'

Comment: and thanks I actually just learned about using mysql_real_escape_string yesterday haven't had a chance to go through all of my files yet, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

you're missing single quotes after the *NOT IN* part. It should be:

```
$sql = mysql_query("
        SELECT EMAIL FROM USERNAME WHERE EMAIL <> '".$_REQUEST['EMAIL']
        ."' AND EMAIL NOT IN ('".$str."')"
    ) or die("Error: ". mysql_error(). " with query ". $sql);
```

Also, as Marc pointed out, you're better using [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on client variables you're going to put inside your queries.

Comment: when I just tried this it now says "Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'd','f'')' at line 1 with query "

Comment: oh, my bad, I didn't think about the possibility that $str had single-quoted text in itself